# can users trigger javascript: function from URL?

Tags: php, javascript

i have a function that calls javascript:del_release_comment(10,12); from the page, if the user has that particular comment.

I wonder if other users can trigger from the URL bar or somehow else this function to delete comments that aren't their.

10 is the news_id and 12 is the comment_news_id, the id of the comment on that particular news.

THe delete is done via AJAX calling a PHP script that does delete on these 2 parameters.
If the javascript function can be called by hand i'd have to re-enforce the little PHP script that deletes the comment. Also, is it possible to call that particular PHP script by name in the URL directly ? It uses _POST vars, not GET.

Thanks.

code for deleting the comment :

```
$query_del_comment = "DELETE from myl_news_comments WHERE comment_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment_news_id'])."' AND news_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['news_id'])."'";
$result_del_comment = mysql_query($query_del_comment) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please add some server side code like the one you are handling the delete request.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clients can execute any HTTP request they like using a variety of techniques (including calling your JavaScript functions, or building it manually).

You must perform authentication / authorisation on the server to ensure that the request to delete something is from someone authorised to delete that something.

Comment: thanks...i'm re-enforcing my little AJAX php external routine to delete only if _SESSION var corresponds to the current logged in person. it's totally safer.

Comment: also i'm planning to switch to PDO style for my portal, will need to look more into it and read up some more documentation, seems straight forward, and i will dedicate the next 2 months into converting throughout all my portal all mysql_* queries to PDO....just to keep up with the development and to ward off any possible SQL injections. that would be a hard one, but it makes up for the safeness of it.